Trayodashi vrat we can do without puja?
What if someone want to do Shiva's trayodashi vrat but don't want to do puja. If he/she spend full vrata time without food, just don't do vrata puja, in that case, will vrata be acceptable by Lord Shiva? Even if not fully but can be get partial phal of vrata like this?
Or puja is mandatory, without it we won't get even 1% of vrata phal OR we will be ended up doing any sin by not performing puja and this making Shiva angry towards ourselves like this?

Simply fasting on the Vrata day will also give fruits if not full fruits
